# How can I emphasize with any color on a sentence?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to know; How can I emphasize the sentence? I mean, when I write for example: Can I...

And if I use: IOS, then what/how can I do in order to do this?

Or, If I want to emphasize a whole text so that it will be 100% clear. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the color of text, see the thread on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-stack-overflow-question-editor). You can make something **bold** or *italic* for emphasis.

To do this, do either one of:

- Put *'s around the text. Two for bold and one for italic. e.g **this** would be rendered as **this**.
- Select the text and Press Ctrl+b for bold and Ctrl+i for italic.
- Select the text and click on the formatting buttons:
  [image]

The more important thing to work on is to keep your text concise, coherent and neat. If you absolutely need to write more than a few sentences then put them in proper paragraphs. People don't like to read long chunks of un-punctuated rambling.

Comment: Yes,this what I was trying to say.

Comment: And actually,I referred on IOS:How can I do that?