# Can you allow users to use any kind of colors?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I’m asking this because, I think it might be very helpful for many users, because, this can make things much easier for the readers to understand. Like I want to use red bold so that other readers will see that it is as something important, or to write caution with red bold or simply red, this an example only.

**R-1:** Can you please make rules of when we can use a specific color?

In case you don’t know the meaning of “R” this letter it means request.

What do you say about that?

Answer (score 2):

To implement a feature, there's a development process, which includes implementing, testing, debugging, and so on.  Consequently, StackExchange prioritize the most important feature requests.  It takes a lot more than *might be very helpful for many users* for a feature request to be implemented.

#### At meta.SE

This was raised on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115455/351283), 2011, and listed as [status-declined](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined); answers there write:

> Having colors would enable people to abuse them.
>
> I don't see any value such a feature would give except for adding complexity and the potential for rather horrific looking questions.
>
> I think if used cautiously, colours can help to underline the content of a text very effectively. Of course, the opposite can happen as well; but to me the risk should not be too big.

So there's a bit of debate, but it was declined.  It's just not important enough, especially when there are users opposing it.

#### What's the point?

What does this achieve that is not already achievable?  See [markdown help](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and some other options in [a prior meta.Islam.SE post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3220/17163).  Also...

[image: If it's hugely important, colored text can be used in images.]

#### Demonstrate it's importance

If you want to convince people that this is important, I suggest:

1. giving a concrete example of how colors would benefit the site,
2. giving an explanation as to how this cannot already be achieved in other ways, and
3. justifying why this is not a once-off example.

Given that Islam.SE has been around for years, and (to my knowledge) nobody except you has requested this, it's still extremely unlikely.

---

*Side note*: is it really necessary to ask so many questions on this single topic?

1. [How can I emphasize with any color on a sentence?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3162/17163)
2. [Can you tell me how is this called and how can I make this?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3184/17163)
3. [How can I change colors of the word?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3203/17163)
4. [How to write with any color?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3243/17163)
5. [Can you allow users to use any kind of colors?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3245/17163)